# R: Loop with dynamic variable names

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run the following loop

```
for(i in 1:5) { 
  nam <- paste("cons_", i, sep = "")
  new_data[nam] <- with(new_data, ifelse(cons>2 & remember==1 & comp==i, 1, NA))
  new_data[nam] <- with(new_data, ifelse(cons<3 & remember==1 & comp==i, 0, new_data[nam]))
}
```

new_data[nam] <- with(new_data, ifelse(cons2<3 & aided==1 & **brand==i**, 0, **new_data[nam]**))

The **SECOND** part in bold is where I am having trouble, because I'd like some of the existing data (NAs really) to not get overwritten. I thought I could just assign the variable name, but it doesn't evaluate this properly. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a `dput` of the `head` of the data (is there a better way to do this). The idea is you have several people providing a rating each for `comp` (it's a stacked dataset). I've noticed the loop I tried only actually fills out the first variable if I make it nested.

```
structure(
  list(
    id = 1:6,
    comp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
    remember = c(1L,
                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
    cons2 = c(3L,
              1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L),
    cons_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
    cons_2 = c(NA,
               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cons_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cons_4 = c(NA,
               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cons_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cons_6 = c(NA,
               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cons_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cons_9 = c(NA,
               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  ),
  .Names = c(
    "id",
    "comp",
    "remember",
    "cons2",
    "cons_1",
    "cons_2",
    "cons_3",
    "cons_4",
    "cons_5",
    "cons_6",
    "cons_7",
    "cons_9"
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: Could you supply the structure of `new_data`?

Comment: Try `new_data[[nam]]`. See `help("[")`.

Comment: *but it doesn't evaluate this properly*...please show us current result and your desired result.